# Django: ignora JS y CSS especificados en class Media de los formularios

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Estoy intentando aprender Django y hasta ahora no he tenido problemas en ir incorporando nuevas opciones. Parece que he tropezado en la piedra de los JS y CSS a servir con un formulario.

Utilizando formularios de clase (AuthenticationForm, PasswordChangeForm y similares) defino en `class Media:` los archivos CSS y JS que debe utilizar el formulario, pero ni escribiendo la URL completa logro que se utilicen esos ficheros.

Un ejemplo de clase:

```py
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_('username'), help_text=_('help text: login username'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': _('e.g. johndoe')
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
            'required': _('error: required username')
        })
    password = forms.CharField(label=_('password'), help_text=_('help text: login password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': _('e.g. c^n6*u!S')
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
            'required': _('error: required password')
        })
    
    class Media:
        js = ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/show-password.js',)
```

también lo he intentado utilizando `js = (settings.STATIC_URL + 'js/show-password.js')` y la opción que debería ser la normal `js = ('js/show-password.js')`.

Todos los ficheros estáticos se están mostrando correctamente en esa URL (no es un fallo de los ficheros estáticos), e incluyendo directamente el fichero JS en la plantilla base funciona sin problema… pero no si lo limito a los formularios.

He utilizado como referencia la documentación oficial [Form Assets (The Media class)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/topics/forms/media/) y tampoco es un problema de no entender inglés.

En la vista simplemente utilizo el formulario:

```py
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts:view', kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
```

y por el código que se recibe en el navegador, todo está en orden… menos los ficheros JS y CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado gracias a [la respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558533/django-widget-media-doesnt-work)

La cuestión tiene lógica, pero no está recogida en la documentación oficial y no ha sido fácil encontrar la respuesta.

Al crear un formulario o un *widget* se puede especificar ficheros JS y CSS necesarios para que se muestren y comporten apropiadamente.

Esto se hace añadiendo `class Media:` en la definición de la clase:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForms):
    # las definiciones de campos del formulario

    class Media:
        js = ('js/show-password.js',)
        css = {
            'all': ('css/forms.css',)
        }
```

Para utilizar estos ficheros en la plantilla hay que incluirlos; parece de perogrullo, pero en la documentación oficial no se explicaba y parecía que Django se ocupaba “milagrosamente” de ello.

Si en la plantilla base se han definido bloques para CSS extra y para JS extra:

```
#accounts/login.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static i18n %}

{% block main_content %} Contenido y el formulario {% endblock main_content %}

{% block meta_title %}{% trans "login" %}{% endblock meta_title %}

{% block extra_css %}{{ form.media.css }}{% endblock extra_css %}
{% block extra_js %}{{ form.media.js }}{% endblock extra_js %}
```

Espero que sea útil.